# RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem fetching data from the simulated model but get error code : RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#33496 relayoutBoundary=up15 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

My model . /models/messagemodel.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Message {
  final String name;
  final String message;
  final String imageProfile;
  final String date;

  Message({
  required this.name, 
  required this.message, 
  required this.imageProfile,
  required this.date});
}

final List<Message> messages = [
Message(name: 'อลงกรณ์ ดอนสุวรรณ', message: "สอบถามตัวสินค้าหน่อยครับ", imageProfile:'https://i.pinimg.com/236x/cc/00/75/cc007582be734f3eb536e45006ba8ac1.jpg',date: '2023-05-31'),
Message(name: 'รัชนก ธานี', message: "สินค้ายังมีอยู่ไหมคะ", imageProfile:'https://blogs.jaidee-webdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/253-2532493_thinking-man-png-free-download-transparent-png.png',date: '2023-05-30'),
Message(name: 'Gordon Ramsey', message: "Hello , I need to your product", imageProfile:'https://www.nicepng.com/png/detail/340-3400291_smiling-person-png-man-with-arms-crossed-png.png',date: '2023-05-29'),
];
```

This is My View Page
./messageview.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rj38_seller/environment/themes.dart';
import 'package:rj38_seller/models/messagemodel.dart';
import 'package:rj38_seller/views/message/components/listmessage.dart';

class MessageView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MessageView({super.key});

  @override
  State<MessageView> createState() => _MessageViewState();
}

class _MessageViewState extends State<MessageView> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Themes().backgroundTheme,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: false,
        titleSpacing: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Themes().white,
          elevation: 0,
        title: Transform(transform: Matrix4.translationValues(30.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        child: Text('Message',style: TextStyle(color: Themes().black)))
      ),
      body:  SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      const ListView.builder(
        itemCount: messages.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
            child: ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(messages[index].imageProfile),
              ),
              title: Text(messages[index].name),
              subtitle: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(messages[index].message),
                  Text('Date: ${messages[index].date}'),
                ],
              ),
              onTap: () {
                // การทำงานเมื่อกดที่รายการข้อความ
                // คุณสามารถเพิ่มโค้ดที่นี่เพื่อรายละเอียดเพิ่มเติมหากต้องการ
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    ],
         ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2C23.png)

How to fix it thank you sir

Comment: remove `singleChildScrollView` and the `Column` widget .

Comment: i remove already but have same a problem

Comment: your `body` widget should be a `Listview.builder` without `const`

Comment: same brother :( without const but have a same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have placed an infinitely tall child widget inside a `Scrollable` widget, causing this error. To resolve the issue, you can try the following:

- Remove the `SingleChildScrollView` and `Column` widgets and keep only the `ListView` widget to make the entire page consist of only the `ListView.builder`.

OR

- Add `shrinkWrap: true` and `physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` properties to the `ListView` widget, so you can use other widgets inside the `Column` along with the `ListView`. You must be remove `const` tag from `ListView.builder`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: 0




I remove the Circleavatar and work but , what wrong with CircleAvatar

Comment: It might be happening because you haven't specified height to child widget, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Remove SingleChildScrollView And Column Widget and simply add ListView.Buidler in Scaffold Body Like Below Code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: false,
          titleSpacing: 0.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          elevation: 0,
          title: Transform(
              transform: Matrix4.translationValues(30.0, 0.0, 0.0),
              child: Text('Message', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)))),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: messages.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
            child: ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(messages[index].imageProfile),
              ),
              title: Text(messages[index].name),
              subtitle: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(messages[index].message),
                  Text('Date: ${messages[index].date}'),
                ],
              ),
              onTap: () {
                // การทำงานเมื่อกดที่รายการข้อความ
                // คุณสามารถเพิ่มโค้ดที่นี่เพื่อรายละเอียดเพิ่มเติมหากต้องการ
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing SingleChildScrollView and Column widget will help.